# Returning top timestamp for a name in a ID

Tags: sql

I'm stuck writing the SQL query for this table:

```
TABLE (
  "BUILDING_ID" NUMBER,
  "NAME" VARCHAR,
  "ENTERED_TIME" TIMESTAMP,
  "COL1" VARCHAR
  PRIMARY KEY(BUILDING_ID, NAME, ENTERED_TIME)
);
```

I want to only return rows of `(BUILDING_ID, NAME, ENTERED_TIME)` for when `NAME="FRED"` was the last one (Highest Timestamp) entering the building.

For example if there are these rows:

```
(1,"FRED","4/12/2020","value")
(2,"TOM","4/14/2020","value")
(3,"FRED","4/12/2020","value")
(3,"BOB","4/13/2020","value")
(5,"FRED","4/12/2020","value")
(6,"TIM","4/12/2020","value")
```

it will return these rows:

```
(1,"FRED","4/12/2020","value")
(5,"FRED","4/12/2020","value")
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by entered_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where name = 'FRED'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, RANK() is the answer:

```
WITH ranked_entries AS (
    SELECT 
        building_id, 
        name, 
        entered_time, 
        col1, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY building_id ORDER BY entered_time DESC) AS rnk
    FROM 
        entries 
)
SELECT 
    building_id, 
    name, 
    entered_time, 
    col1
FROM 
    ranked_entries
WHERE 
    name = 'FRED' AND 
    rnk = 1;
```